# IOS in-app purchase verfication or Data retrive

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I made In-App purchase for consumable product in my ios app. purchase flow completely working fine. but i have some few doubts in my point, so let any one clears my doubts its very useful for me to fine tune my app better

1. after purchasing i can get receipt data, can i send this receipt data to server
2. during purchase if user internet disconnect, how i can get purchase information like its succeed, or its failed. i need this kind of information to be stored in back-end server
3. like wise i need to store all purchases to my back-end server. like user a purchased this item with time & date. user b attempt to purchase this item but poor network purchase not succeed

if i store these data its useful for me to analyze in-app purchases happened inside my ios application.

its look like a dashboard to find all these information. hope any one will help me to solve this.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can send the receipt date to the server and you should to it to verify receipt instead of verify on local.
2. You subscribe the changes on payment queue, and when the device reconnected to the internet, you'll receive the payment events. Additional, there're product types you have to provide UI for users to restore purchased products.
3. It depends on your product requirements, for me, only successfully purchased receipts are stored (around ~1gb per day)

Comment: how to subscripe payment queue?? and i need to view users purchase info by back-end

Comment: Suppose i send receipt data to backend server(my own server) and then i get receipt data insert in DB, i get success message from backend server, after now i call the "Skpayment.queue.finishtransaction()"